# Os.walk function gives None value to path

Tags: python, linux, operating-system

I tried to use os.walk function to retreive some data (tsv files) from different folders. The folder names are in a list. This is my code:

```
import os

def find_folders(folders):
    for folder in folders:
       return folder

def find_directories(search_path,folder):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(search_path):
        for dir in dirs:
            if dir == folder:
                open_dir = os.path.join(root,dir)
                return open_dir
def find_abundance_files(directory):
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(directory):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".tsv"):
                return file
def main():
    search_path = r"/mnt/e/Thesis/Parasponia_RNAseq/kal_out/"
    folders=["Medtru_BUD","Medtru_FLOWER","Medtru_LEAF","Medtru_NODULE","Medtru_ROOT","Medtru_SEED"]
    folder = find_folders(folders)
    directory = find_directories(search_path,folder)
    abundance_file = find_abundance_files(directory)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

The problem is that the `os.walk` refuses to read the search_path as a path and returns "None".
I also thought the problem occurs because the path is linux related, I used windows path and still I faced the same issue. Do you know why it does that?
This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gidio\PycharmProjects\flask_blog\CalculateRPK_paired_end.py", line 105, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\gidio\PycharmProjects\flask_blog\CalculateRPK_paired_end.py", line 100, in main
    abundance_file = find_abundance_files(directory)
  File "C:\Users\gidio\PycharmProjects\flask_blog\CalculateRPK_paired_end.py", line 81, in find_abundance_files
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(directory):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\os.py", line 342, in walk
    return _walk(fspath(top), topdown, onerror, followlinks)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

Comment: This code shouldn't even compile because of the `:` after `search_path == "/mnt/e/Thesis/Parasponia_RNAseq/kal_out/":` Please post your actual code.

Comment: Last line in "main()" uses a variable "directory" not defined anywhere.

Comment: Sorry guys my bad. It's fixed now

Comment: `directory = find_directories(search_path.folder)` Is that supposed to be `directory = find_directories(search_path, folder)`?

Comment: Yes that's correct, fixed too

Comment: `find_folders` just returns the first item in the list. You can probably get rid of that function altogether and just do: `for folder in folders:`

Comment: okay noted. can I also use yield instead of return ?

Comment: Sure you can use `yield`. But you would still need a loop: `for folder in find_folders(folders): `